# How to detec if browser was reload - React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, page-refresh

Can you help, please?

I'm trying a way for  detec if browser was reload and the most answers about this say something like

```
const typeOfNavigation = (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0] as PerformanceNavigationTiming).type
        
 if(typeOfNavigation === 'reload'){
   localStorage.removeItem('products-list');          
 }
```

**The problem** is that the code above since user make refresh the browser , the type is **always** stay like **"reload"** and that Api does not exist method for refresh or clear to "navigation", Ideally, it would return to its original state. "navigate", but that doesn't happen, So I need that something dinamic.

I found the code above,  work perfect for me , but is **deprecated**

```
if(window.event?.type === "loadend"){
   localStorage.removeItem('products-list')
}
```

In short,  Can someone help me about that question , any idea is welcome, I need know **each time** when the user make refresh the browser through f5 or clicking the button,

Obs: I'm using React/Typescript

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the `beforeunload` event. This event is fired when the user navigates away from the page, closes the window/tab, or reloads the page. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event).